# Display two dates in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display two dates in my react application. It should be displayed as Date1 - Date2. Here is the code.

```
export const formatFromToDates = (fromDate, toDate) => { 
   return (
     <Moment format='YYYY/MM/DD'>{fromDate}</Moment> -
     toDate === null ? ' Now' : <Moment format='YYYY/MM/DD'>{toDate}</Moment>
    ); 
}
```

But is only displays the second date. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to put `{}` around your JSX expression for `toDate`:

```
export const formatFromToDates = (fromDate, toDate) => { 
    return (
        <Moment format='YYYY/MM/DD'>{fromDate}</Moment> -
        {toDate === null ? ' Now' : <Moment format='YYYY/MM/DD'>{toDate}</Moment>}
// -----^------------------------------------------------------------------------^
    ); 
};
```